# How to validation in jquery sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Validation Code is like this :

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    if ($("li.msg").length && $("li.msg ol li").length) {
        alert('success');
        return false;
    }
    else if (!$("li.msg").length && !$("li.msg ol li").length) {
        alert('You do not add a room type');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert('Please drop customer to a room type');
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Here is an example of the HTML that is not working correctly:

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="POST">
  box 2 (Room Type)
  <br>
  <select id="room_type">
    <option value="1">Single Room</option>
    <option value="2">Double Room</option>
    <option value="3">Twin Room</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="Add" style="margin-top: -10px;" id="add_room">

  <ol class="example areaDROP vertical" id="room_list">
    <li class="room_number msg" data-id="1" data-name="Single Room">
      Single Room
      <ol>
        <li class="">Lionel Messi</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="room_number msg" data-id="1" data-name="Single Room">
      Single Room
      <ol>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Demo & Complete Code is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/mL7qr5z1/

My validation is working in some cases, but in certain cases like the form above, it is showing success when it should be showing, "Please drop customer to a room type".

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: You should post the HTML that is not validating correctly here too, since your validation involves looking at tag and class names in the document. The problem is that as soon as you have one room with a customer added, `$("li.msg ol li").length` will return true. Because there is an `li` with the class `msg` and it contains an `ol` and an inner `li`. You need to loop through and check that *all* of the list items contain that.

Comment: @James Hay, Thank you very much. I want to ask again. If my case like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/mL7qr5z1/1/ . Whether the validation that I made are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change your validation to:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
    var isSuccess = true;
    $("li.msg").each(function(index, element) {
        if ($(this).find("ol > li").length == 0) {
            isSuccess = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if ($("li.msg").length > 0 && isSuccess){
        alert('success');
        return false;
    }
    else if (!$("li.msg").length && !$("li.msg > ol > li").length){
        alert('You do not add a room type');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert('Please drop customer to a room type');
        return false;
    }
});
```

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $("ol.mauDIDROP").sortable({
    group: '.example'
  });

  $("ol.areaDROP").sortable({
    group:  '.example',
    drop: false,
    drag: false,
  });

  $("ol.areaDROP>li>ol").sortable({
    group:  '.example',
    drop: true,

  });

  $('#add_room').click(function(){
    var text = $("#room_type option:selected").html();
    var room_type_id = $.trim($('#room_type').val());

    $('#room_list').append('<li class="room_number msg" data-id="'+room_type_id+'" data-name="'+text+'">'+text+'<ol></ol></li>');

    $("ol.mauDIDROP").sortable({
      group: '.example'
    });

    $("ol.areaDROP").sortable({
      group:  '.example',
      drop: false,
      drag: false,
    });

    $("ol.areaDROP>li>ol").sortable({
      group:  '.example',
      drop: true,

    });

  });



  $('#myForm').submit(function(){
    var isSuccess = true;
    $("li.msg").each(function(index, element) {
      if ($(this).find("ol > li").length == 0) {
        isSuccess = false;
        return false;
      }
    });
    if ($("li.msg").length > 0 && isSuccess){
      alert('success');
      return false;
    }
    else if (!$("li.msg").length && !$("li.msg > ol > li").length){
      alert('You do not add a room type');
      return false;
    }
    else {
      alert('Please drop customer to a room type');
      return false;
    }

  });
});
```

```css
ol.nested_with_switch li, ol.simple_with_animation li, ol.default li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
ol.vertical {
  margin: 0 0 9px 0;
}
/* line 12, jquery-sortable.css.sass */
ol.vertical li {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  color: #0088cc;
  background: #eeeeee;
}
/* line 19, jquery-sortable.css.sass */
ol.vertical li.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
/* line 24, jquery-sortable.css.sass */
ol.vertical li.placeholder:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  top: -4px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: red;
  border-right: none;
}

/* line 32, application.css.sass */
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* line 34, application.css.sass */
ol i.icon-move {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* line 36, application.css.sass */
ol li.highlight {
  background: #333333;
  color: #999999;
}

/* line 39, application.css.sass */
ol li.highlight i.icon-move {
  background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
}


.content{
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/js/jquery-sortable.js"></script>


<div class="content">
    box 1 (Customer)
    <ol class='example mauDIDROP vertical'>
        <li>Valentino Rossi</li>
        <li>David Beckham</li>
        <li>Eden Hazard</li>
        <li>Lionel Messi</li>
        <li>Christiano Ronaldo</li>
        <li>Frank Lampard</li>
    </ol>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <form id="myForm" action="" method="POST">
        box 2 (Room Type)
        <br>
        <select id="room_type">
            <option value="1">Single Room</option>
            <option value="2">Double Room</option>
            <option value="3">Twin Room</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="Add" style="margin-top: -10px;" id="add_room">

        <ol class="example areaDROP vertical" id="room_list">
            <!-- <li class="room_number msg1">Deluxe Room<ol><li>John Terry</li></ol></li>
              <li class="room_number msg1">Family Room<ol><li>Jose Mourinho</li></ol></li> -->
        </ol>

        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working. I want to ask again. If my case like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/mL7qr5z1/1/ . Whether the validation that I made are correct?

Comment: I assume yes. What is important you understood you have to cycle on the children elements to check if room added there must exist a customer. Many thanks

Comment: Thank you. I want to ask again the last. I change  my code like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/mL7qr5z1/2/. My case like this : http://imgur.com/PD7PKQJ. When I click button save, there is message "success". whereas the placement is wrong. I find it difficult to improve the condition

Comment: I need you help, Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640041/how-to-validation-of-input-text-field-in-ajax?noredirect=1#comment58961736_35640041